# Can I ask this question: Is there any aspect of a nuclear weapon test that cannot be simulated using super computers?

Tags: discussion

Nuclear weapons tests are experiments carried out to determine the effectiveness, yield, and explosive capability of nuclear weapons. However, these days most nuclear weapon states uses Super computers to simulate nuclear weapon testing.

Therefore, can all the parameters of a nuclear test be determined using computer simulation only?

Answer (score 3):

I would close this question because the relevant information is typically considered too sensitive for public distribution without government review.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Are there any **rules** in this Community or Stack Exchange that deals with `sensitive questions`? If yes, can you please share the link so that I am up to speed with the rules & regulations pertaining to asking questions. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think so, because this sort of scenario hasn't come up in the past. As a general rule, however, I would say that if you are asking for information that arguably requires some sort of security clearance in a moderated forum, you are likely to run into issues. [Nuclear weapons information can fall under that category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_clearance), and it's of a national security nature such that I don't feel comfortable having that information on this forum.